# Bundle Multiple CSS Served From a CDN?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, cdn, bundling-and-minification

We are looking into the new **bundling** feature of **ASP.NET MVC 4** and are wondering if there are any advantages to **bundling CSS files** that are **served from a CDN**?

Is there even a way to bundle multiple files served up from a CDN in ASP.NET MVC 4?
This doesn't work:

```
var cdnCssPath = "http://MyCdn/css/";    
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css", cdnCssPath)
            .Include("~/Content/site.css")
            .Include("~/Content/Test1.css")
            .Include("~/Content/Test2.css")
            .Include("~/Content/Test3.css")
            );
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I've been looking into the same thing but haven't found anyway to achieve this. We currently use Talifun script crusher but this appears to have the same limitation in that the CDN support is done on a group, not per file. I guess it makes sense because there's no direct way to bundle the separate CDN based files into a single file.

Comment: @Ken Burkhardt i have the same question on that how can load multiple css using cdn have you any idea about this then please also let me know?

Answer (score 20):

First of all it depends on if you have access to a CDN  where you can upload your own files or if you're using, for example, google's CDN to get external libraries like jQuery.

If you pull files from a CDN and bundle them, you would lose the advantage of using a CDN unless you're able to upload your new bundled file to the CDN.

For example if you get jQuery and jQuery UI from google's CDN and bundle them, you're no longer using google's CDN, you're instead serving up local resources (the created bundle).
You may have reduced the number of requests, but instead of 2 requests too google's CDN (which has a high probabillity to be cached already by the users browser) there's one request to your server (which is not as likely to be cached).

So in short I would say that there's no advantage to bundle files together that comes from a CDN, however uploading your bundled files to a CDN is different story.

Do note that it is possible to use use CDN for bundles though:
look at the "Using a CDN" part of [this article](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)

Edit: Here's an article that explains when to use a CDN or not and why, a bit more indepth than my answer http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/13-11-07/know-when-to-cdn.aspx

Comment: From what I can tell from reading the article that you linked to; it looks like you can only have one file in your bundle if that bundle points to a CDN. There definitely seems to be a trade-off here: reduced number of HTTP requests that you can get by bundling multiple files vs the caching\ availability of a CDN.... Not obvious to me the best way to go !!